# Python xml etree find parent node by text of child

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML that's like this

```
<xml>
    <access>
        <user>
            <name>user1</name>
            <group>testgroup</group>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>user2</name>
            <group>testgroup</group>
        </user>
    <access>
</xml>
```

I now want to add a `<group>testgroup2</group>` to the user1 subtree.

Using the following I can get the name

```
access = root.find('access')
name = [element for element in access.iter() if element.text == 'user1']
```

But I can't access the parent using name.find('..') it tells me

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'.
```

Is there any possibility to access the exact `<user>` child of `<access>` where the text in name is "user1"?

Expected result:

```
<xml>
    <access>
        <user>
            <name>user1</name>
            <group>testgroup</group>
            <group>testgroup2</group>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>user2</name>
            <group>testgroup</group>
        </user>
    <access>
</xml>
```

*Important notice: I can NOT use lxml to use getparent() method, I am stuck to xml.etree*

Comment: You've set `name` to a list, so of course there's no `find` attribute, as list objects don't have that method.

Comment: I know that. That's what the error message tells me obviously. But how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Show us your expected XML result.

Comment: I don't know but I thought I already wrote what I wanted to add. Nevertheless I have updated the question with my expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this, if anyone is interested in doing this stuff in xml instead of lxml (why ever).

According to suggestion from

http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm#accessing-parents

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse(my_xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
access = root.find('access')

# ... snip ...

def iterparent(tree):
    for parent in tree.getiterator():
        for child in parent:
            yield parent, child

# users = list of user-names that need new_group added
# iter through tupel and find the username
# alter xml tree when found

for user in users:
    print "processing user: %s" % user
    for parent, child in iterparent(access):
        if child.tag == "name" and child.text == user:
            print "Name found: %s" % user
            parent.append(et.fromstring('<group>%s</group>' % new_group))
```

After this et.dump(tree) shows that tree now contains the correctly altered user-subtree with another group tag added.

Note: I am not really sure why this works, I just expect that yield gives a reference to the tree and therefore altering the parent yield returned alters the original tree. My python knowledge is not good enough to be sure about this tho. I just know that it works for me this way.

Answer (score 0):

> To do that, using 'find', you need to do like this: for ele in name:
>       ele.find('..') # To access ele as an element

Comment: I didn't want to access ele. I need ele.getParent() but that doesn't exist in xml.etree: <user> is parent, I want to find <name> and append to <user> another <group> entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive method to iterate through the tree and capture the parents.

```
def recurse_tree(node):
    for child in node.getchildren():
        if child.text == 'user1':
            yield node
        for subchild in recurse_tree(child):
            yield subchild

print list(recurse_tree(root)) 
# [<Element 'user' at 0x18a1470>]
```

If you're using Python 3.X, you can use the nifty `yield from ...` syntax rather than iterating over the recursive call.

Note that this could possibly yield the same node more than once (if there are multiple children containing the target text). You can either use a set to remove duplicates, or you can alter the control flow to prevent this from happening.

Comment: In this case, "node" will hold the parent so I could access it with node.append(et.fromstring(...ect ect in the if statement, right? I have read about yield but yet don't fully understand how it works internally...

Comment: @dreamyrhodes Yes, `node` will hold the parent. Explaining yield is beyond the scope of a comment, but basically it's an alternative to constructing a list of the parent elements in the function.

Comment: Yes of course it would be too much for a comment. I am just puzzled that this works (as well as my own solution below) and yielding objects of the tree and then altering them makes the original xml tree altered. Thanks anyhow also since your suggestion is shorter than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use findall() method to get the parent node that match the name='user1'. see below code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml') #build tree object using your xml
root = tree.getroot() #using tree object get the root

for parent in root.findall(".//*[name='user1']"): 
    # the predicate [name='user1'] preceded by asterisk will give 
    # all elements where child having name='user1'
    parent.append(ET.fromstring("<group>testgroup2</group>"))


# if you want to see the xml after adding the string
ET.dump(root) 
# optionally to save the xml
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: Pasting code alone will not help. Please provide brief explanation what does it do?

Comment: emphasize the code with comments